# Calculating occurrences of unique numbers inside a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large data (.tr file). I have read the file and renamed the columns in a data frame (df). I managed to go over all of the existing records and check certain conditions. I need to calculate how many unique value(from src.port column) existed within the whole file? The following MWE will illustrate my question.

```
# The df looks like:
     st time      from to protocol size flags    flowID src.port dst.port  seq   pktID
      + 0.100000    1   2      tcp   40 -------      1      5.0       2.1     0     0
      - 0.100000    5   0      ack   40 -------      1      5.1       2.3     0     0
      r 0.102032    1   2      tcp   40 -------      1      5.20      2.5     0     0
      r 0.102032    1   2      tcp   40 -------      1      5.11      2.6     0     0
      r 0.102032    1   2      tcp   40 -------      1      3.0       2.0     0     0
      + 0.121247   11   0      ack   40 -------      1      11.1      2.10    0     1
      r 0.132032    1   2      tcp   40 -------      1      3.0       2.0     0     0
      r 0.142065    1   2      tcp   40 -------      1      3.0       4.0     0     0

 # I have tried the following:
   unique<-0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    # feel free to suggest different way from the below line. 
    # I think using the name of column would be better 
    if(df[i,1]=="r" && df[i,3]== 1 && df[i,4]== 2 && df[i,5]== "tcp" ){
     # now this condition is my question
     # check if df[i,9] is new not presented before...Note 5.0 is different from 5.1 
     # check if df[i,10] is 2 and ignore any value after the dot (i.e 2.x ..X means any value)
     # so the condition would be:
      if ( df[i,9] is new not repeated && df[i,10] is 2.x)
          unique<-unique+1
     }

   }
```

from the sample data the expected output:is unique=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply subset the relevant data and use `unique`. Here, I've chained together all of your conditions and extracted just the "scr.port" column and used `unique` on the result.

```
unique(mydf[mydf[, "st"] == "r" & 
              mydf[, "from"] == 1 & 
              mydf[, "protocol"] == "tcp" & 
              grepl("^2.*", mydf[, "dst.port"]), 
            "src.port"])
# [1] 5.20 5.11 3.00
```

Wrap that in `length` to get the count that you're looking for.

Alternatively, create a subset of your data and count the number of rows.

```
out <- mydf[mydf[, "st"] == "r" & 
              mydf[, "from"] == 1 & 
              mydf[, "protocol"] == "tcp" & 
              grepl("^2.*", mydf[, "dst.port"]), ]
nrow(out[!duplicated(out$src.port), ])
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you, both are working,I like the second one. If I want to make the above code run for a given range of time like between 0.100000 and 0.132032. Other than subset(df, time<0.132032) any suggestions !

Comment: @SimpleNEasy, you can add other conditions in the same form, for example, `& mydf[, "time"] > 0.1 & mydf[, "time"] < 1.32032`.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy, the `grepl` line can also be replaced by something like `floor(mydf[, "dst.port"]) == 2`. I offered the `grepl` solution in case that was a character column, and not a numeric column.

Comment: If I want to add more o/p information such printing how many times a certain src.port appears in the data. After calculating `out`, I've used `out[duplicated(out$src.port), ]`,it prints the repeated row.However I want the o/p like: source 3.0  2. which means source 3 repeated 2 times. Any suggestion !